# How to indicate base url in Flask Restplus documentation

Tags: flask, swagger-ui, flask-restplus

Could you please describe how to indicate the base URL in the documentation automatically generated by Flask Restplus?

I am running the following code but nothing shows up in the swagger UI:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app,
    title='Data Quality Framework API',
    version='v0.1',
    doc='/data_quality_framework/api/documentation',
    contact='me@xxx.com',
    base_url='/test')
```

[image]

Comment: See also: [Why do I get a 404 despite having @app.route('/') when I have Flask-Restplus?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56539574/562769)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By default, when using this pattern (ie. with `app` as constructor argument), the API is on the root endpoint (ie. `/`) and the swagger documentation is on the API root (ie. still `/`).

You have multiple possibilities:

**Use a blueprint to change the API root**

If you want to keep the documentation on the API root but change the API root, [use a blueprint](http://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scaling.html#use-with-blueprints) to register you API where you want.

```py
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from flask_restplus import Api

app = Flask(__name__)
blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/test')
api = Api(blueprint)
app.register_blueprint(blueprint)

assert url_for('api.doc') == '/test/'
```

**Only change the documentation location**

If you want to keep the API root at the same place but only move the documentation location, Flask-restplus allows you to specify it with the `doc` parameter.

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app, doc='/test/')

assert url_for('doc') == '/test/'
```

You can also combine both. See http://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/swagger.html#customization for more details on advanced documentation customization.

Comment: Thank you, as discussed [here](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/286) I was able to achieve this by removing the url_for itself and putting the documentation url directly in `api = Api(..., doc='/documentation')`

Comment: Hello Alexis and Axel, your conversation is little bit misleading because its incomplete, even in the conversation on github link. in simple words all that is needed is to have something like `url_prefix="/api"` in the creation of blueprint object and say `/doc` in doc parmater of api object creation time. so the final url becomes `/api/doc` and `Base URL`   will be `/api` totally make sense. the documentation link added by Axel explains much better.

Comment: Yeah for me the assert line wasn't necessary:  
api = Api(app, doc='/api/v1', prefix="/api/v1")

Answer (score 5):

you could define it with *prefix* parameter. I've tried it on version 0.13.0.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restplus import Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app, prefix='/api')
```

Answer (score -3):

add it line

```py
from flask import url_for
```